# Extracting data from nested JSON using python

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary, nested

I am hoping someone can help me solve this problem I am having with a nested JSON response. I have been trying to crack this for a few weeks now with no success.

Using a sites API I am trying to create a dictionary which can hold three pieces of information, for each user, extracted from the JSON responses. The first JSON response holds the users uid and crmid that I require.

The API comes back with a large JSON response, with an object for each account. An extract of this for a single account can be seen below:

```
{   
'uid': 10, 
'key': 
        '[
        N@839374', 
        'customerUid': 11, 
        'selfPaid': True, 
        'billCycleAllocationMethodUid': 1, 
        'stmtPaidForAccount': False, 
        'accountInvoiceDeliveryMethodUid': 1, 
        'payerAccountUid': 0, 
        'countryCode': None, 
        'currencyCode': 'GBP', 
        'languageCode': 'en', 
        'customFields': 
                        {
                        'field': 
                                [{
                                'name': 'CRMID', 
                                'value': '11001'
                                }
                                ]
                        }, 
        'consentDetails': [], 
'href': '/accounts/10'}
```

I have made a loop which extracts each UID for each account:

```
    get_accounts = requests.get('https://website.com/api/v1/accounts?access_token=' + auth_key)
    all_account_info = get_accounts.json()
    account_info = all_account_info['resource']
    
    account_information = {}

    for account in account_info:
        account_uid = account['uid']
```

I am now trying to extract the CRMID value, in this case '11001': {'name': 'CRMID', 'value': '11001'}.

I have been struggling all week to make this work, I have two problems:

1. I would like to extract the UID (which I have done) and the CRMID from the deeply nested 'customFields' dictionary in the JSON response. I manage to get as far as ['key'][0], but I am not sure how to access the next dictionary that is nested in the list.
2. I would like to store this information in a dictionary in the format below:

{'accounts': [{'uid': 10, 'crmid': 11001, 'amount': ['bill': 4027]}{'uid': 11, 'crmid': 11002, 'amount': ['bill': 1054]}]}

(The 'bill' information is going to come from a separate JSON response.)

My problem is, with every loop I design the dictionary seems to only hold one account/the last account it loops over. I cant figure out a way to append to the dictionary instead of overwrite whilst using a loop. If anyone has a useful link on how to do this it would be much appreciated.

My end goal is to have a single dictionary which holds the three pieces of information for each account (uid, crmid, bill). I'm then going to export this into a CSV document.

Any help, guidance, useful links etc would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what do you think that `append to the dictionary` means?

Answer (score 0):

In regards to question 1, it may be helpful to print each level as you go down, then try and work out how to access the object you are returned at that level. If it is an array it will using number notation like [0] and if it is a dictionary it will use key notation like ['key']

Regarding question 2, your dictionary needs unique keys. You are probably looping over and replacing the whole thing each time.

The final structure you suggest is a bit off, imagine it as:

```
accounts: {
    '10': {
        'uid': '10',
        'crmid': 11001, 
        'amount': {
            'bill': 4027
                  } 
          },
    '11': {
        'uid': '11',
        'crmid': 11011, 
        'amount': {
            'bill': 4028
                  } 
          }
          }
etc.
```

So you can access `accounts['10']['crmid']` or `accounts['10']['amount']['bill']` for example.